# OSX - ssh keeps failing for different reasons

Tags: macos, ssh, timeout

I am using ssh to connect to my digitalocean droplets normally. Recently, all of them stop working suddenly and I can't access them but they highlight different reasons.

1. `Connection closed`
2. `Operation Timeout`

when running using `-v`, I get the following:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 12.345.678.900 [12.345.678.900] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file cooing.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file cooing.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 46.101.107.176:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by 12.345.678.900
```

What could be the possible cause for such issue as I can't figure it out

Comment: I suggest you can try some ssh client like Putty to see if the the ssh protocol is functioning first. If it is not working, then this is not OSX issue, vice versa

Comment: @Bilo I downloaded it and it worked. Also normal ssh works without changing anything. Any idea how can I further trace this issue?

Comment: @Bilo
What are you running on the other end and what version of SSH is it running?
OpenSSH has gone through many phases and the host you are connecting too could be using an outdated ssh causing it to close. 

I have seen this problem with a variety of products that use older versions of openssh and had to use a ssh client on the mac to connect to them.

Comment: @Tim I am trying to connect from macbook to ubnutu machine hosted on digitalocean. I believe my ssh is update and I constantly update any packages on the server as well. The problem is the issue occurs randomly every now and then so nothing leads to the cause of the issue so far.

Comment: I just wanna ask one more thing, have you recently updated your mac?

Comment: I have updated to elcapitan but that was like a couple of months ago nothing recently